# MySQL Syntax Error -- But only for certain variables

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm coding a website in PHP/MySQL. I have a single line that works for 4 digit numbers passed through $_GET, but not for a single digit or a three digit.

Here's the code I've used.

```
    $planid = $_GET["planid"];
    $dbObj->dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM plans WHERE blnWebEnabled='yes' AND planid='$planid'";
```

Using var_dump, I've verified that the $planid is correct: 
    string(1) "1" 
And the actual SQL query statement is correct: 
    string(60)

```
SELECT * FROM plans WHERE blnWebEnabled='yes' AND planid='1';
```

In fact, I've typed the exact same, character for character statement straight into the MySQL console and came up with a single record, as expected. But for some reason, when this hits the browser, it gives me this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I've also tried making the SQL statement say:

```
SELECT * FROM plans WHERE blnWebEnabled='yes' AND planid=1;

SELECT * FROM plans WHERE blnWebEnabled='yes' AND planid = 1;

SELECT * FROM plans WHERE blnWebEnabled = 'yes' AND planid = '1';
```

... and other variations.

The crazy thing is that it will happily take 4 digit numbers. The database key field I'm using is the primary key, and it's type `int(11)`.

Could someone please help me? I am about to tear my hair out in frustration!

Thank you in advance for your time!

**EDIT**: *More information from a little further testing* -- 
Taking out "blnWebEnabled = 'yes'" still gives the same error. 
Trying to add leading zeroes to $planid until it has a strLen of at least 4 still gives the same error, though that query also works when entered directly into the MySQL console. 
The following query works just fine through the PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM plans WHERE blnWebEnabled='yes' AND planid='1000';
```

Comment: Please try it like `SELECT p.* FROM plans p WHERE p.blnWebEnabled='yes' AND p.planid='$planid'` is this working?

Comment: Why are you not using bind variables for dynamic input?

Comment: What type is blnWebEnabled and planid? Sanitized your input.

Comment: have succeed with this query manually in PHP myadmin?

Comment: @MateiMihai: Same error using that

Comment: @DCoder: I'm not really sure what you mean

Comment: @twodayslate: blnWebEnabled is type char(3) and planid is type int(11)

Comment: @PrasathAlbert: Yes, this query has succeeded when manually typed into the MySQL console. I do not currently have PHP myadmin.

Comment: You should be using PDO or MySQLi with [parametrized queries](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Statements_With_Parameters) instead of blindly inserting dynamic input into the query. It will not necessarily fix this particular problem, but it's a very important issue nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

i think the `$planid` is empty. print the `$planid` value and check again.

Comment: var_dump of $planid: string(1) "1"